# Выплнение скрипта внутри ajax кода

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Есть скрипт:

```
$(".delete-btn").on("click", function () {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "delete.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {answId: answId},
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $.notify({
                // options
                icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign',
                message: data 
                },{
                // settings
                type: 'danger'
                });
            }else {
$(this).closest(".block-smallContainer").closest(".wall-content").closest(".block").hide(100);
            }
        }
    })
})
```

Проблема в том, что код: `$(this).closest(".blocksmallContainer").closest(".wallcontent").closest(".block").hide(100);`
не выполняется.

Приходиться делать так:

```
$(".delete-btn").on("click", function () {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        url: "delete.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {answId: answId},
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.length > 0) {
                $.notify({
                // options
                icon: 'glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign',
                message: data 
                },{
                // settings
                type: 'danger'
                });
            }
        }
    })
    $(this).closest(".block-smallContainer").closest(".wall-content").closest(".block").hide(100);
})
```

Мне надо, чтобы этот код выполнялся внутри `else`.

Comment: Покажите функцию, из которой вы вызываете `$.ajax`. У вас проблема с потерей контекста `this`.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Обновил

Comment: Правильно @StepanKasyanenko говорит, у Вас замыкание происходит в этой функции success: function (data) {} и контекст this уже принадлежит ей. Вам надо $(this) присвоить к переменной и уже ее использовать в функции.
varName.closest(".block-smallContainer").closest(".wall-content").closest(".block").hide(100); 

Как-то так.

Comment: @i.prikot или использовать стрелочную фуксию

Comment: Проблема решена. Я как вы сказали прсвоил $(this) к переменной и потом вызвал её все заработало. Спасибо

Comment: Тогда вам стоит удалить вопрос.